# Restore database to new database and files using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, database-restore

I have been trying unsuccessfully to restore a database to a new database but keep getting errors saying that the existing files cannot be overwritten. How do I specify a new database and files?

**Update:** The command I am using is below. TestDB_2.0 does not exist yet, I am wanting it to be created from the backup file.

```
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance SERVER-NAME\MSSQL2014 -Database TestDB_2.0 -BackupFile D:\TestWebsite\TestDeployments\testdb.bak -SqlCredential [sa, $pw]
```

The error I get is:

```
Restore-SqlDatabase : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL2014\MSSQL\DATA\TestDB.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by 
database 'TestDB'.
At D:\Projects\Scripting\Scripts\Powershell\Backup-SqlDatabase.ps1:11 char:1
+ Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance WIN-OJR1ILRNQUF\MSSQL2014 -Database TestDB_2 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Restore-SqlDatabase], SmoException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.RestoreSql 
   DatabaseCommand
```

Comment: It would be beneficial if you should us the code you were working with so we can build off of it instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Post the exact error and the exact code and we may be able to help

Comment: Data and log file names are saved inside the backup. And used by default. You need to use additional parameters to specify file names other than default.

Comment: Hi @abatishchev, do you know what parameters they are? I have reviewed the documentation for the cmdlet and I cannot find which one to use.

Comment: From the error you are receiving, it looks like the database file TestDB.mdf already exists. If you are OK with it being overwritten use the "-ReplaceDatabase" flag in your Restore-SqlDatabase command. If not, here is a reference that might help with other options, such as relocating files.  (https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/backup-and-restore-sql-server-with-the-sql-server-2012-powershell-cmdlets/)

Comment: From the doc `Get-Help` I found `-DatabaseFile` but didn't find one for the log. Please try and post an error if any

Comment: Also google for `-RelocateFiles`, it seems it can be used to specify both file names.

Comment: The documentation for this PS module is awful. Actually it just doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi @abatishchev, the -DatabaseFile restore type is different, its when you are just targeting the files apparently.

Comment: Oh, ok,I see. Then try relocate files. This is what you are actually doing. I saw a similar question here on SO about this parameter.

Comment: It looks like @JanChrbolka has identified the solution. In the linked article there is a section stating that if you want to restore to new files you have to use a SMO object and pass that. Seems it's just not possible using only this cmdlet.